# java accept user input to 5 integers

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi how in java we can limit numbers of integers a certain user input? Below is my code of accepting user inputs, how can i ensure that only accept 5 integers from users? Thanks

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        int a;
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string");
      a = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println("You entered integer "+a);

    }
```

Comment: You could introduce a for loop which runs for exactly 5 times and inside scan for the number.

Comment: Well it's currently only accepting *one*. If you want to accept five, you'll need to call `nextInt()` five times. You could do that in a loop, or just with five calls.

Comment: You need to limit integer input to max 5 such as(1 to 5) or something else such as combination of five like (12548,85698)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
  int a[] = new int[5];
  int i = 0; 
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(i<5)
  {
  System.out.println("Enter an integer");
  a[i] = in.nextInt();
  i++;
  System.out.println("You entered integer "+a[i-1]);
  }

}
```

For a[i] to be between 1 and 100

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      int a[] = new int[5];
      int i = 0; 
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(i<5)
      {
      System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 100");
      a[i] = in.nextInt();
      if(a[i]>=1 && a[i]<=100) 
      {
        i++;
        System.out.println("You entered integer "+a[i-1]);
      }
      }

    }
```

Comment: works well , how we can filter the results so that user inputs fall in a range from 1 - 100 ?

Comment: @zlippr.. You should first try it on your own. I don't think its that tough to check whether a number is in between that range or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop that iterates only 5 times and take the input inside that `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a static field as count=0,

Check whether a>0
If it is , increment count by 1

When count is already 5, dont let the user input anything